# Android Google sign in returns RESULT_CANCELLED

Tags: java, android, google-developers-console

The app I'm developing uses google sign. I want to authenticate these users on my server. It used to work, but after changing the computer I develop on and in stead of running on an avd I now use a real device. After these changes google sign in stopped working and always returns `Activity.RESULT_CANCELLED` So I tried to reconfigure everything in dev console with no luck. I followed the docs exactly for about 3 times now.

What I did:

- went to this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
- Configured a project and entered the android debug keystore sha-1 fingerprint
- Went to credentials page to get the `Web client (Auto-created for Google Sign-in)` client-id
- Create `GoogleSignInOptions` using that client-id:

```java
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(clientId)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

- I also tried all other client-id's listed on the credentials page without luck

I'm not using the release build variant yet btw.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared my `applicationId` in my module level build.gradle file differed from my package name defined in my manifest file. Even though google states to use the package name in your manifest when you configure a project, you still have to make sure your build.gradle file has the same `applicationId` defined for some reason.

Answer (score -2):

[image: FireBase console]Use google account which register with play console then login firebase console and select project then go-> Settings -> Integrations -> Enable Google Play tab

then check

Comment: Google play console costs money. Last time I did this, I got it to work without spending money.

Comment: after July 2019 it's not available for free