# registerForActivityResult with Google Sign In not working

Tags: android

Trting to replace `startActivityForResult`, which is deprecated, with the new `registerForActivityResult`. My old Google sign in code no longer works. Instead of RESULT_OK I get RESULT_CANCELED. Help is appreciated.

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;

private SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.googleBtn); 

GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder( GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN )
            .requestIdToken( getString(R.string.REQUEST_ID_TOKEN) )
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

GoogleSignInClient gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient( this, gso );


private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
        new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if ( result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    try {
                        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
                        GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);

                        if( account != null && task.isSuccessful() ) {
                            firebaseAuthWithGoogle( account );
                        }
                    } catch (ApiException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        signIn();
    }
});

private void signIn() {
    //signInIntent.putExtra("requestCode", RC_SIGN_IN );
    //startActivityForResult( signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN );
    activityResultLauncher.launch( gsc.getSignInIntent() );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent 3 hours debugging it on my end but it is not the same as your issue. Since I was implementing this for the first time I forgot the debug key. However, since you're upgrading you must have had your token/id set up before.

I don't imagine anything will stand out, but here is my code that I adapted from your code and the docs that is working nicely for this:

```
import static android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResult;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;


public class GoogleAuth {
    public GoogleSignInClient gsc;

    public GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder( GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN )
            .requestIdToken( "my-token-ADSFASFASDFDSFADFS" )
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    public GoogleAuth(Context context) {
        gsc = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, gso);
    }

    public ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getloginResultHandler(ComponentActivity activityParam) {
        return activityParam.registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == RESULT_OK) {
                            System.out.print("Hooray!")
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

The main difference is the factory method that I made which I found needed because I had this error: [How to resolve the error "LifecycleOwners must call register before they are STARTED"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64476827/how-to-resolve-the-error-lifecycleowners-must-call-register-before-they-are-sta)

So to resolve it that question said you aren't supposed to call registerForActivityResult from an activity while it is running, so I actually call that before the super in the onCreate, save the result, and then use that in the onClick().

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        googleAuth = GoogleAuth(this@MainActivity as ComponentActivity)
        launcher = googleAuth.getloginResultHandler(this@MainActivity as ComponentActivity)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

I assume you're using a ComponentActivity based on your two param call to registerForActivityResult(), so that is the same as me and should be fine.

After the initialization during onCreate I call the function from `onClick`:

```
onClick = {
    launcher.launch(googleAuth.gsc.signInIntent)
}
```

From my research I found this comment:

> @ZaidMirza I am developing on Android sdk 21 to 33. For sdk> 30 however with the new api ActivityResult is always CANCELED. –
> Phantom Lord
> Aug 9 at 7:36
> [OnActivityResult always returns RESULT CANCELED (Code: 0) on Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70952359/onactivityresult-always-returns-result-canceled-code-0-on-android-11)

So that makes it look like it could be a general problem. Unfortunately there are no answers there.

Another questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68697829/activityresultlauncher-resultcode-always-returns-0-with-cancelled-result) showed some success for adding `.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);` to the intent which I tried when I was stuck. However this intent in our case is certainly already trying to do that.

These questions:

- [Getting result code always RESULT_CANCELED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69304175/getting-result-code-always-result-canceled)
- [Google sign-in fragment returning RESULT_CANCELED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49019676/google-sign-in-fragment-returning-result-canceled)

point out that you need launch mode to be standard in your manifest for the activity. If it is single task that is a reason that causes an issue with this.

This question: [Android Google sign in returns RESULT_CANCELLED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225973/android-google-sign-in-returns-result-cancelled) showed there can be an issue if your packageId is different in your build.gradle and manifest.

Hope there's even a small chance something in here catches your eye and you find the issue!

Comment: where do you call getloginResultHandler ?

Comment: I just updated my answer with 2 more code snippets that show where it is being called.

Comment: just tested the code and man you rock ! thanks

Comment: Awesome to hear! Do you know what the exact problem was in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that issue is not related to the `ActivityResult Launcher API`. Instead, check if you have registered the app with the correct `SHA-1` key for both `debug` and `release` flavours.

You can get the debug SHA-1 key by using this command on command Run window,

```
gradle signInReport
```

It will return all the SHA-1 keys for the modules present. So check all the SHA-1 keys for debug as well as release types.

Comment: That's not the issue. startActivityForResult is working well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing well,

You have to Create A GoogleSignIn Client and pass your GoogleSignInOptions.Builder as param in order to get callback in your getloginResultHandler

Attaching the sample Code below:-

```html
 private void SignIn(){
        GoogleSignInOptions gsc = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken("my-token-ADSFASFASDFDSFADFS")
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient =  new GoogleSignIn.getClient(context,gsc);
        googleSignInLauncher.launch(googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent());
    }
```

Now you will get the callback in your activityResultLauncher`s  onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) method.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see the config is OK, this issue maybe related to 2 reasons

- Android Developer Options -> You must be turn off `Don't keep activities` option.
- The launch-mode of your activity, activity result just return result in the same tasks activities

> if the activity you are launching uses Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

I hopping to help you resolve this issue.